# Sargenes vs. Kittel

Tags: minhag, clothing, high-holidays, yekke, kittel

This is fairly simple:

Growing up in the US, the only white robes available for wearing during Rosh haShannah and Yom Kippur are standard [kittels](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/kittel). I have heard that the kittel worn in Germany prior to the Shoah (called a *sargenes* in Western Yiddish) is quite different.

What are the differences between the Eastern Kittel and the Western Sargenes and what does the latter look like?

Comment: FWIW I remember seeing pictures that the Lubavitcher Rebbe wore a pull-over kittel, more similar to tachrichim in that it doesn't have buttons, and without any design on the garment.

Comment: @Efraim, I wonder if he needed to get it custom-made. Chabadniks I've met wear regular kittels of he variety worn in the US and Israel.

Comment: Where I come from the Sargenes was put on over the head and has no pockets, buttons or frills.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up in Alsace (France) which is geographically and culturally close to Germany. Definitely Yekke land. I only heard about Sargeness as a child.

For what I can remember it is mostly the same: a while long fabric robe with a belt and long sleeves which is a reminder or the burial shrouds (or maybe the actual burial shrouds that will be used after 120 years, to be checked).
The sargeness I knew where made of a thicker material and with more lace than the kittel I know. But that might be because they were not made in China and sold for 20 shekel in Mea Shearim.

[This http://catalogue.mahj.org/collec.php?q=1&o=16](http://catalogue.mahj.org/collec.php?q=1&o=16)  photo  is from the collections the Paris Jewish Museum.  It does not quite look like what I remember but it might just mean my father was wearing a different type.

Comment: Alsace is considered Germany for liturgical purposes. They follow similar customs to what was historically followed in Frankfurt a/M

Comment: I assume there were also no pockets, like on normal kittelach.

Comment: @ezra, not as far as I'm aware. I've never seen a kittel, sargenes, or tachrichim with pockets.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked at [kayj.net](https://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/193-white-kaepchen-sargenes-tallis-for-rqh-and-yqk).  The answer was:

> The original sargenes is similar to the tachrichim, closed from the front and from behind, and is put on over the head